# how to devide Table column into more then one column in html bootstrap

Tags: html, css

I want to make an HTML table with divided into more then one columns just like ms word. Can any one please guide me how I can achieve my goal?

[image: desired output]

Comment: Kindly do not post images/url to external links and also refer to this [ask]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is code for what you want, as shown in image or in ms word.

> Use "rowspan" & "colspan" for merging of cell

```css
table {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-collapse: collapse
}

thead {
  background: #f2f2f2;
}

table th,
table td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 5px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">CH</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Max Marks</th>
      <th colspan="3">Marks Obtained</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Grade</th>
      <th rowspan="2">GP</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>TH.</th>
      <th>PR.</th>
      <th>Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>7</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```